# Laravel - Include bootstrap in node modules folder

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am new with Laravel and I am thinking about one thing.

I have a node_modules folder with bootstrap 4. But I don't want to use the CDN in order to link my template into bootstrap. I want to link the folder that npm installed in my project to my template.

I have my gulpfile.js but I don't think that's what I need.

```
elixir((mix) => {
    mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/', 'public/fonts');
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .browserify('app.js');
});
```

I'm searching in lot of websites but I don't have a good solution. Do you have some Ideas in order to guide me ?

Thank you for taking time on my problem and have a Merry Christmas =)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please indicate all of your css and js files in gulpfile.js elixir with this way:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir'),
gulp    = require('gulp'),
htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
require('laravel-elixir-uncss');

elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;
elixir.config.css.minifier.pluginOptions = {
keepSpecialComments: 0
};

elixir(function(mix) {
mix.styles(['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/bootstrap.css', 'table.css', 'font-awesome.css', 'main.css'], 'public/css/app.css');
});

elixir(function(mix) {
mix.scripts(['jquery.js', 'main.js', 'table.js', 'init.js'], 'public/js/app.js')
});

elixir(function(mix) {
mix.compress();
});
```

So finally all css files will make one file name app.css and all js files will make one final file name app.js
Works fine for me, hope this one will work for you too !
Thank You

Comment: I used the code you gave me, thank you =) But How can I link with my template to the node_module ?

Comment: Use: {{ url("../node_modules/style.css") }}